# Javascript showing up in error logs

Tags: javascript, php, drupal

Suddendly i started noticing strange urls in my drupal site error logs. They have url encoded javascript functions and i have no clue where they come from or how to reproduce them. Since the url doesn't exist it shows up on error logs as "Access Denied".

URL

> mydomain.com/function%20(a,c)%7Bvar%20b=this.slice((c||a)+1||this.length);this.length=0%3Ea?this.length+a:a;return%20this.push.apply(this,b)}

Referral

> mydomain.com/start?created=All&search=&sort_bef_combine=created%20DESC&sort_order=DESC&sort_by=created&page=1

Other example

URL

> mydomain.com/function%20(a,c)%7Bvar%20b=this.slice((c||a)+1||this.length);this.length=0%3Ea?this.length+a:a;return%20this.push.apply(this,b)}

Referral

> mydomain.com/some-random-url

Another function

> mydomain.com/function(b)%7Bif(void%200===this%7C%7Cnull===this)throw%20new%20TypeError;var%20a=Object(this),e=a.length%3E%3E%3E0;if(0===e)return-1;var%20c=0;0%3Carguments.length&&(c=Number(arguments[1]),c!==c?c=0:0!==c&&c!==1/0&&c!==-(1/0)&&(c=(0=e)return-1;for(c=0<=c?c:r.max(e-r.abs(c),0);c

Does anyone knows why this is happening? It's not always the same function, but this one seems to be showing more often than the rest.

I've logged the user agent string of one of the offenders and they were using Firefox 25, but when i access the site using Firefox 25 nothing strange shows up in the logs.

Is it bad coding?

Some browser extension goin' crazy?

Some insight needed please. Thanks

EDIT: Whatever it was, it got fixed or they got fed up. Thanks to all intervenients for the responses.

Comment: start logging referers as well. it could every well be some OTHER site that has highly broken links pointing at your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People (or bots) are trying to exploit your website. Hope you're sanitizing your get variables.

Comment: To expand: someone's trying to see if they can get arbitrary javascript to execute by putting malicious data into various parameters. This exploit strategy is called "cross-site-scripting" or XSS.